# Find devices via bluetooth and then get specific data from database? (Without pairing)

Tags: ios, database, networking, bluetooth

I want to get info about bluetooth devices without having to enter a passcode and pair the device. The thought is that when a bluetooth device i near my device i want to get information about the device pulled from a database. Like if the device i found is registered in My database the app Will, (without pairing) get the info i want from the database. So the bluetooth is only for sensing that a device is near.

Can i do that in iOS without pairing? Maybe get a bluetooth Mac address and then check in the Database for registered devices matching that bluetooth Mac?